# How to get list of kinesis streams with cli command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis

I want to get list of kinesis streams using cli command

> aws kinesis list-streams

gives me list of all kinesis stream, How can I filter it using cli command?

Comment: You'll have to use `jq` or something similar, kinesis doesn't support a `--filter` option

Answer (score 1):

**Describe Specific stream**
aws kinesis describe-stream --stream-name stream name

**List All Streams**
aws kinesis list-streams

**Filter Stream from the list**
aws kinesis list-streams | grep "Stream Name"